# The number of records that is the table shows in .dbf file is not match with the real number of records

Tags: files, foxpro

I have some .dbf files made in VFP. I have to work with them and occasionally edit it. Recently I noticed that one of .dbf`s is running in a wrong way. The number of records that is the table shows is not match with the real number of records. I have tried to modify the header of this table to reflect an estimated number of records but with no result. How can I get my origin files back?

Comment: Restore from backup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a hexidecimal editor and open a .dbf file in it. This tool is located at tools\hexedit\hexedit.app.

1. The header bytes that contain the record count are located in columns 4, 5, 6, and 7 of address `00000000` (topmost row).
2. Go to the address and then change the data in this column to double zero.
3. Next, open this file in VFP as a table and note that the record count is zero.

I have found this thread for you https://getsatisfaction.com/impathic/topics/corrupt-dbf-files
where a similar issue is discussed.